# Push footer down to page when div content is generated?

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I have the page as the showed picture

[image]

When something is clicked on the right column, the DIV on the left column will appear with generated content. This Div has a fixed height but its position may vary depending on the clicked position on the right column. As you can see when the Div appears, the footer is not pushed down.

I have tried many solutions on SO to re-position the footer as in [How to keep footer at the bottom even with dynamic height website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815784/how-to-keep-footer-at-the-bottom-even-with-dynamic-height-website)
but none of them works for me. Maybe I have done something wrong?

My footer's css:

```
#footer{ color: #666666; background: #D3D3D3; border-top: 1px solid #AAA;
                padding: 1em; margin-top: 0; position:absolute; width:100%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/WTUPn/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">

</div>

<style type="text/css">
    body, html { height: 100%; }
    #wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: -90px;
        position: relative;
    }
    #footer, .push { height: 90px; }
    #footer {
        background: #000; color: #FFF;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently you'll need to insert more code but your footer cannot be positioned absolutely as it takes a specific position irrespective of other divs