# HTML heights and a footer

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm having some trouble getting a [website](http://ddcm.ugent.be/) to look the way I want it to. I have a footer that I want to have at the bottom of the page (but does not stick to the bottom of the viewport if the content is large). The current situation is almost fine, though I want the body and html tag to take up 100% of the viewport if the content is small. If I add height: 100%; to the html and body tags, the home page looks fine **but** the [members page](http://ddcm.ugent.be/index.php/en/who-are-we) displays the footer somewhere in the middle of the page as the height of the html and body tags somehow seems to match the size of my viewport instead of the content. The footer has the `color-footer` class (you can verify this yourself by dynamically changing the css rules through your browser's developer tools).

OAS: this site was developed by an external and runs on Joomla. I'm not a web developer and I'm just getting a headache from trying to get this to work. I've gone through a dozen of guides but it looks like this time Google couldn't give me the simple solution. After hours of meddling in the developer mode with chrome I can't get it to work so I was wondering if anyone could figure out the correct css rules to add to my stylesheet so I get the desired behaviour.

Comment: You can try to add min-height for the section tag who have id "maincontent". In your style you can add #maincontent{min-height:600px;} for exemple

Comment: Adding this rule does not make my html and body tag take up the entire viewport if the content it small. In fact, it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: I have copied the content from "http://ddcm.ugent.be/index.php/en/news" and I added 
`<section id="maincontent" style="min-height:600px;">`
Now, the footer is at the bottom ...

Comment: Yes, I am doing exactly this yet on the home page, the footer is still sticking to the bottom of the content, which does not fill my viewport.

Comment: Ok, I understand .
`<div class="color-footer" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;">`

Comment: @S.B. That just makes it so the footer doesn't scroll at all...

Comment: @JamieBarker exactly, and this is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JavaScript/jQuery solution:

```
function CheckFooterPos() {
    var Footer = $('.color-footer');
    var BottomOfScroll = $('html').scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    var BottomOfFooter = Footer.offset().top + Footer.height();
    if (BottomOfFooter < BottomOfScroll) {
        Footer.css('bottom', '-' + (BottomOfScroll - BottomOfFooter) + 'px');
    } else {
        Footer.css('bottom', '0px');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        CheckFooterPos();
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
        CheckFooterPos();
    });
    CheckFooterPos();
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but I have no idea how to even add JS to the Joomla page. It took me a while to figure out how to even edit the css using the Template Manager but I don't see any JS in there, only php and css.

Comment: If you have access to your index.php, you can add it into the head tag within a `<script type="text/javascript">` tag

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you :) though I am more than satisfied with this result, I was wondering if you would also know the css solution to this, or is the whole site just a mess because of joomla?

Comment: I don't know of one I'm afraid, otherwise I would have posted one. I have updated the answer to include a resize listener, just in case the scroll function doesn't fire if you resize the browser window.

Comment: May have found [a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/huston007/c4bauxny/2/), however it may need some html changes

Answer (score 0):

Because it's `position:absolute` so, it will so in the middle of the screen.

Just remove  `position: absolute;` from `.color-footer {` will solved your issue.

```
.color-footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 66px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
//    position: absolute; //remove it.
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The current state is based on http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page. I've tried removing position:absolute; as you suggest but the footer no longer sticks to the bottom nor does the html/body take up the entire viewport if the content is small.

Comment: @Warkst Add `section {
    min-height: 600px;
}` will stick you footer to bottom even content is small. and `html { height:100% }`.

Comment: Combining all those steps (removing absolute positioning, setting html height to 100% and adding min-height to the maincontent section) fixes the members page but does not work for the home page.

Comment: The footer is sticking to the bottom of my content but the content is not filling the home page. You can check this yourself by going to the URLs I provided and dynamically changing the css through dev tools. I want the footer to stick to the bottom of the page and the page to stretch to the size of the viewport if the content is small.

Answer (score 0):

You can set footer position using javascript if you are not able to fix its position through css, though its possible through CSS too.

http://josephfitzsimmons.com/simple-sticky-footer-using-jquery/

and I guesss
[How to keep footer at the bottom even with dynamic height website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815784/how-to-keep-footer-at-the-bottom-even-with-dynamic-height-website)
this can also help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but those guides make a sticky footer that is always on top and always on the bottom of the viewport. I want my footer to always appear below my content and have my content stretch to at least the size of my viewport.

Comment: var layout = function(){ if ($(window).width() > 767) {
     $(".body-content-class").css("min-height", $(window).height() - $("nav").height()  - $("footer").height());
}
}
$(window).resize(layout);  

Above code is Simply setting height of middle content of page. Height will be $(window).height() - nav bar height and footer height.