# Keep that Footer at the bottom

Tags: html, css

So I've managed to figure out how to set the footer at the bottom of the webpage.

However, I am running into problems when I have to scroll down a page, or when I zoom and unzoom. The footer doesnt actually stay at the bottom, and it seems to be just sitting in a fixed position to the size of the web page.

**This is my html/php coding for the main webpage:**

```
<html>
   <head>

<title> First Html! </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bdpastudents.com/~t4645202/2015-2016/%22my%20first%20html%20website%22%20assignment/firsthtml.css">


<?php include("header.php"); ?>




</head>
<body>
<?php include ("navigation.php"); ?>




<p> Welcome to my website! Have a look around! Have fun!<br>
Oh and dont forget... Images are not just images.</p>


<br>
<br>
<center>
<a href="http://bdpastudents.com"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-o27DZE9cGwE/VpE4Thx7gSI/AAAAAAAAAIA/mXv9P9UQ3Ew/w488-h650-no/socer%2Bpic.jpeg" height="300" width="200"></a>
</center>

</body>



</html>

<?php include ("footer.php"); ?>`
```

**This is my footer coding:**

```
<div id="footer">


<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="none">

<title> First Html! </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bdpastudents.com/~t4645202/2015-2016/%22my%20first%20html%20website%22%20assignment/firsthtml.css">



<?php


// Prints the day, date, month, year, time, AM or PM
 echo date("d/m/Y h:i A") ; 
 echo " Craed!." ;
 ?>

</div>
```

**And this is my css:**

```
body {

height:100%;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

padding: 0;

margin: 0;

background-color: #a2a2a2;
}

p {
    text-align:center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 150%;
  }

ul {
    color: white;
    font-size:150%;
    }

#fade {
display: none;
}




 #head {

    background-color: #65659a;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;

}

#footer {
    height:50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #65659a;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#nav {
    position: absolute;
    line-height:30px;
    background-color: #000000;
    height:85%;
    width:120px;
padding:5px;
}


#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size:125%;
}

#nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 93%;
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there something that I am missing?

Sorry for the long post, im pretty new to this.

Thanks!

Comment: `<?php include ("footer.php"); ?>` is outide the `</body></html>` tags for one thing, rendering as invalid HTML markup.

Comment: and your `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bdpastudents.com/~t4645202/2015-2016/%22my%20first%20html%20website%22%20assignment/firsthtml.css">` belongs in `<head></head>`. and `<div id="footer">...</div>` in `<body></body>`. Time to learn HTML 101. http://htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/

Comment: `<title> First Html! </title>` also belong in `<head>` and is the title of the document not `<div>`.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a total *mish-mash* and tearing the hell out of HTML markup language. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML - http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/

Comment: take a look into using `flexbox` layouts - they'll give you the layout you want easily

Comment: The reason I had the footer sitting outside of the  html tag, was due to the fact that if it were above it, the footer would jump up to the middle of the page. As for the link rel, it IS already in the head section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep footer at the bottom even with dynamic height website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815784/how-to-keep-footer-at-the-bottom-even-with-dynamic-height-website)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to clean the code a little bit, because it was so messy. I haven´t checked the CSS code so I don´t really know if there´s something wrong with it. Just fixed the HTML. I properly added the `<head>` section and fixed the problem with the markup for the `<footer>`

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekymq6xv/)

Regards!

PS: Also I would suggest studying more about HTML. You can learn a lot [here.](http://www.w3schools.com)

Comment: There seems to be quite a lot of invalid markup on that fiddle

Comment: @RamRaider *Quite*, if not worse.

Comment: You said that you fixed the problem with my footer, however, there seems to be no changes. Try to zoom in and zoom out. The footer still has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is a shot at it

- Create a big container with an id called 'parent'. This div will occupy your whole screen

  Make the main container a flexbox

  create two flex boxes items in the flexbox

  The first div flexbox will have an id 'main' and will hold are your main contents

  The second div will have an id called 'footer_container' and will hold all the contents of your footer

This is the css styling for the flexbox with id 'parent' and its children

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 95vh; /* Or whatever */
  flex-direction:column;
}

.child {
  width: 100%; 
  margin: none;

  padding:0px;
  }
#footer_container{
  flex-grow:0;
  height:20%;
  margin: auto; 
  border:solid;
}
#main{
  flex-grow:1;
  height:80%;
}
```

I also made some adjustments to your css (Note in you css file change `#footer` position to **relative**)

**snippet below**

```css
body {
height:100%;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background-color: #a2a2a2;
}

p {
    text-align:center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 150%;
  }

ul {
    color: white;
    font-size:150%;
    }

#fade {
display: none;
}
 #head {

    background-color: #65659a;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    

}

#footer {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #65659a;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border:solid black;
}

#nav {
    position: absolute;
    line-height:30px;
    background-color: #000000;
    height:85%;
    width:120px;
padding:5px;
border:solid;
}


#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size:125%;
}

#nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 93%;
}

/*THIS IS THE END OF YOUR CSS STYLE*/

/*FLEXBOX STYLING */

.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 95vh; /* Or whatever */
  flex-direction:column;
}

.child {
  width: 100%; 
  margin: none;

  padding:0px;
  }
#footer_container{
  flex-grow:0;
  height:20%;
  margin: auto; 
  border:solid;
}
#main{
  flex-grow:1;
  height:80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child' id='main'>1
  <?php include("header.php"); ?>
<?php include ("navigation.php"); ?>
  <p> Welcome to my website! Have a look around! Have fun!<br>
Oh and dont forget... Images are not just images.</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <center>
    <a href="http://bdpastudents.com"></a><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-o27DZE9cGwE/VpE4Thx7gSI/AAAAAAAAAIA/mXv9P9UQ3Ew/w488-h650-no/socer%2Bpic.jpeg" height="300" width="200">
  </center>
</div>
  <div class='child' id='footer_container'>
  <div id="footer">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="none">

<?php
// Prints the day, date, month, year, time, AM or PM
 echo date("d/m/Y h:i A") ; 
 echo " Craed!." ;
 ?>
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```